# How to escape an NSString to use in NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

Got this code so far for my send button:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", messageBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUFT8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

However I do get the error "Expected ':'

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to separate the two string construction calls

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", messageBox.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *add = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

Comment: Worked flawless! Many thanks!

Comment: This answer is actually not the best answer. You should only be escaping individual parameter values, not the whole URL. You want: `NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", [messageBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUFT8StringEncoding]];`

Comment: "NSUFT8StringEncoding" should be "NSUTF8StringEncoding."  The "T" and "F" are transposed.

Answer (score 7):

The proper way is not to escape the entire URL. You should only escape individual parameter values.

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", [messageBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUFT8StringEncoding]];
```

Better yet, for readability and easier debugging, do this:

```
NSString *escapedText = [messageBox.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUFT8StringEncoding];
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", escapedText];
```

Comment: Why is this more "proper"?

Comment: @NigamShah Because in this case you only need to encode query parameter values, not the whole URL.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", messageBox.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUFT8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the NSString method to see it clearly:

```
NSString* urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://server.com/ios/add.php?user=iPhone+App&message=%@", messageBox.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding : NSUFT8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score -1):

NSURL will automatically url encode the string when you call NSURL urlWithString this code is not needed.