# Some values not able to send by nsurl?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I have a very strange phenomenon going on with my script. When they are manually made in the script, everything works. When I upload it by iOS, however, it appears that a few of my strings prevent it from sending (when I remove those variables, it sends and executes the insert commands fine again with only the values sent). What I mean by prevent is it fails to send the request at all and I get no insert (the script is designed to insert whatever it gets). Even crazier, is that I nsslog is showing the proper values in those positions just before executing the nsurl. **Therefore, I was curious if it is possible for nsurl to be blocked by some of its own values?** The values that block it are two of my six text fields and one of two nsstrings passed from another view controller. I have given an example of my format here.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://(mywebsite)?string=%@&text=%@", string, textfield.text];
```

Comment: Plain string interpolation can result in invalid URLs. Make sure to utilize appropriate URI component escaping.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014398/how-to-escape-an-nsstring-to-use-in-nsurl , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162653/ios-develoment-why-is-my-nsurlconnection-failing-with-a-bad-url-error-for-onl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're text contains unescaped characters like @, ?, ' or " for example, then yes, the content of your url will cause issues. For example, if i enter "'abcd'&x=50" into your textfield, then your web string will suddenly have an x parameter. Or, you can add in stuff like colons, backslashes etc.

If you correctly escape your string, you should be able to build URL's that way.

Comment: What do you mean "escape my string"...do you have any examples? Really appreciate the response though

Comment: Check the comments on your original question, they will help you out. eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13014398/how-to-escape-an-nsstring-to-use-in-nsurl

Comment: Thanks everyone for the links!